# Capistrano leaving remote tail open

Tags: capistrano

I am using capistrano in a rails-less environment and I'm having a problem with my remote tail task:

```
role :web, "pants@host1", "pants@host2"
task :weberror, :roles => :web do
    stream("tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log | sed \"s/^/\033[0;32m$HOSTNAME:\033[0m /\"")
end
```

If I press `Ctrl+C` to get out of the command, the tail command is left open on the server forever. Is there an alternate way to break with capistrano that cleans up the process or am I doing something wrong with my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the pty option to stop buffering.

stream(..., :pty => true)

Comment: You win! Cheers! Thank you very much for that. Any chance you could tell me what the option actually means?

Comment: pty literally means pseudo terminal or end point - not sure if it makes sense here - they should have said non_buffered => true or buffered => false as the name of the option